# facebook interact most tech

Tags: facebook

I just want to know what tech does facebook use to `show the posts from the friends you interact most`? is there any article related with this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can search for the EdgeRank algorithm, it is the news feed ranking method used in Facebook, it may give you some hits of what you looking for.